# How can I use WTSOpenServer function for the another computer

Tags: c++, windows

Can I use WTSOpenServerA function to enumerate sessions via WTSEnumerateSessionsA function on the another computer in the local network? I'm trying to use the following code:

```
HANDLE server_handle = WTSOpenServerA("192.168.0.3");
    if (server_handle == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "An error occurred whule using function WTSOpenServer. Error code: " << GetLastError() << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    PWTS_SESSION_INFOA session_info;
    DWORD count;
    BOOL res = WTSEnumerateSessionsA(server_handle, 0, 1, &session_info, &count);
    if (!res)
    {
        std::cerr << "An error occurred while using function WTSEnumerateSessionsA. Error code: " << GetLastError() << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

But it gives me the following error:

> An error occurred while using function WTSEnumerateSessionsA. Error
>   code: 5

Error code == 5 is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233737/wtsopenserver-returns-access-denied

Comment: @Xearinox I've already set this option to 1, but it doesn't work

Comment: Do you have correct credentials?

Comment: @Xearinox Where can I set it?